# Improving a long if-else statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement, scripting

Is there a way to write a more elegant code which considers multiple possible combinations than writing a lengthy if-else statement?

I have randomly generated data sets like the ones below but some of the rows can be null sometimes.

> {
> semester1 grade1 final_grade1
> semester1a grade1a final_grade1a
> }
>
> {
> semester2 grade2 final_grade2
> semester2a grade2a final_grade2a
> }

I have already written code for all the possible logical combinations of my data:

```
if [[ -n $semester1 && -z $semester1a && -z $semester2 && -z $semester2a ]]; then
echo "Section 1:$semester1=$grade1, final grade for $semester1=$final_grade1 ."

elif [[ -n $semester1 && -n $semester1a && -z $semester2 && -z $semester2a ]]; then
echo "Section 1:$semester1=$grade1, $semester1a=$grade1a, final grade for $semester1=$final_grade1, final grade for $semester1a=$final_grade1a."

elif [[ -n $semester1 && -n $semester1a && -n $semester2 && -z $semester2a ]]; then
echo "Section 1:$semester1=$grade1, $semester1a=$grade1a, final grade for $semester1=$final_grade1, final grade for $semester1a=$final_grade1a."
echo "Section 2:$semester2=$grade2, final grade for $semester2=$final_grade2 ."

elif [[ -n $semester2 && -z $semester2a && -z $semester1 && -z $semester1a ]]; then
echo "Section 2:$semester2=$grade2, final grade for $semester2=$final_grade2 ."

elif [[ -n $semester2 && -n $semester2a && -z $semester1 && -z $semester1a ]]; then
echo "Section 2:$semester2=$grade2, $semester2a=$grade2a, final grade for $semester2=$final_grade2, final grade for $semester2a=$final_grade2a, ."

elif [[ -n $semester2 && -n $semester2a && -n $semester1 && -z $semester1a ]]; then
echo "Section 1:$semester1=$grade1, final grade for $semester1=$final_grade1 ."
echo "Section 2:$semester2=$grade2, $semester2a=$grade2a, final grade for $semester2=$final_grade2, final grade for $semester2a=$final_grade2a, ."

elif [[ -n $semester2 && -n $semester2a && -n $semester1 && -n $semester1a ]]; then
echo "Section 1:$semester1=$grade1, $semester1a=$grade1a, final grade for $semester1=$final_grade1, final grade for $semester1a=$final_grade1a, ."
echo "Section 2:$semester2=$grade2, $semester2a=$grade2a, final grade for $semester2=$final_grade2, final grade for $semester2a=$final_grade2a, ."

fi
```

Is there a better way for checking this?

Comment: what defines better? Any code that is fewer lines of code will probably be even harder for another person to maintain. Here, at least, it is discrenable what the intentions are. (will be happliy proven wrong about this by members of the `bash` elite ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Questions seeking ways to improve working code without a specific technical question being asked are generally more welcome at [codereview.se].

Comment: I like this question. Truth tables (which is essentially what this is) are lovely, but few scripting languages seem to support them as data structures. To me, this feels like a missed opportunity in computer science.

Answer (score 1):

This loop might do it.  You'd need a second one for the 2nd semester or maybe turn it into a function and then make the vars local:

```
if [[ -n $semester1 ]]; then
  section="Section 1:$semester1=$grade1"
  final="final grade for $semester1=$final_grade1"
  if [[ -n $semester1a ]]; then
    section="$section, $semester1a=$grade1a"
    final="$final, final grade for $semester1a=$final_grade1a."
  fi
  echo "$section, $final"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't doing calculations; I would just assign a default value to undefined variables ("n/a" perhaps?)

```
: ${semester1:=n/a} ${semester1a:=n/a} ${semester2:=n/a} ${semester2a:=n/a}
: ${grade1:=n/a} ${grade1a:=n/a} ${grade2:=n/a} ${grade2a:=n/a}
: ${final_grade1:=n/a} ${final_grade1a:=n/a} ${final_grade2:=n/a} ${final_grade2a:=n/a}
echo "Section 1:$semester1=$grade1, $semester1a=$grade1a, final grade for $semester1=$final_grade1, final grade for $semester1a=$final_grade1a, ."
echo "Section 2:$semester2=$grade2, $semester2a=$grade2a, final grade for $semester2=$final_grade2, final grade for $semester2a=$final_grade2a, ."
```

This task cries out, though, for data structures like lists and dicts/hashes/maps that `bash` is sorely lacking in.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data will also be used for some calculations